# XPath get next element using contains text()?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to use this Xpath to get the second element?
I use the chrome development tool and find two results, how to get the second element
//a[contains(text(), 'https://www')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get nth element, you need to append [nth] to the end, where nth is index of the element you would like to target. For example, to get the second one, try:

```
(//a[contains(text(), 'https://www')])[2]
```

You may find this [page](https://devhints.io/xpath#indexing) useful.

Comment: HI i try not working driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "https")]')[0].text

Comment: indexing in xpath starts with 1